# admin-ajax.php doesn't work when using POST data and Axios

Tags: ajax, forms

I'm trying to create an email signup form with an AJAX request.

Early on I found that Wordpress empties the `$_POST` variable by default. I tried using `admin_post` and `admin_post_nopriv` but neither of those seemed to be working. I'm now trying the following:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_newsletter', 'subscribeToNewsletter');
add_action('wp_ajax_newsletter', 'subscribeToNewsletter');

function subscribeToNewsletter()
{

  echo json_encode([ 'success' => true ]);
```

In my JavaScript, if I use the following:

```
axios
  .post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', {
    'email' : 'abc@xyz.com',
    'action' : 'newsletter',
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  });
```

I get a 400 bad request and a `0` returned. If I change it to:

```
axios
  .get('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?email=abc@xyz.com&action=newsletter')
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  });
```

everything works.

Can `admin-ajax.php` not handle `POST` requests? I don't want to use a `GET` request* for subscribing someone to a newsletter, and I'd like to do it over AJAX.

---

***From W3 schools (which normally I hate but has a good overview on requests):**

Some other notes on GET requests:

- GET requests can be cached
- GET requests remain in the browser history
- GET requests can be bookmarked
- GET requests should never be used when dealing with sensitive data
- GET requests have length restrictions
- GET requests is only used to request data (not modify)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue here, I think, is how *axios* works. Not WordPress. But you're absolutely correct to want to use a POST request here.

By default I believe axios sends data in a POST request as JSON in the body. To get JSON in the body of the request in PHP you need to do this (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047870/issue-reading-http-request-body-from-a-json-post-in-php)):

```
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE); //convert JSON into array
```

The problem with that is that for the `wp_ajax_` hooks to work, WordPress looks for the action in `$_REQUEST['action']`. This won't be set if the action name is part of the request body, since `$_REQUEST` isn't populated when the data is sent as JSON.

I believe that if you want to send POST data in axios the way a form does, and access it with `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`, then you need to send it as [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) in the script:

```
var data = new FormData();

data.append('email', 'abc@xyz.com');
data.append('action', 'newsletter');

axios
    .post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
    });
```

PS: Just so you're aware, this syntax: `response => {`, [won't work](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions) in any version of IE.

Comment: Wow, that's a fantastic insight. Can confirm everything you said. This has tripped me up multiple times in the past, I'm thrilled to have it all working now –thanks.