# Vue and wordpress.Bad Request ajax request

Tags: javascript

First off, I'm not using wp in REST API mode. I'm simply using vue for an UI I wrote for an custom admin page. I'm using a development server spun up from webpack, I enqueue the scripts as so:

```
enqueue_admin_scripts_and_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_editor();
        wp_enqueue_script("chunk-vendors", "http://localhost:8080/js/chunk-vendors.js", array("jquery-ui-core", "jquery-ui-tabs"), "", true);
        wp_enqueue_script("guides-dev", "http://localhost:8080/js/app.js", array("chunk-vendors", "jquery-ui-core", "jquery-ui-tabs"), "", true);


    /* GRAB THE CATEGORY SO WE CAN PROVIDE THEM TO THE FRONT END */
    wp_localize_script("guides-dev", "wp_vue", array(
        "categories" => get_categories(array(
            "hide_empty" => false
        )),
        "ajaxurl" => admin_url("admin-ajax.php")
    ));
}
```

my wordpress code:

```
function blackout_admin_test() {
    wp_json_success_send("Hi");
    die();
}

add_action("wp_ajax_blackout_admin_test", "blackout_admin_test");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_blackout_admin_test", "blackout_admin_test");
```

I have wp_localize_script sending ajaxurl to the front end:

```
wp_localize_script("guides-dev", "wp_vue", array(
            "categories" => get_categories(array(
                "hide_empty" => false
            )),
            "ajaxurl" => admin_url("admin-ajax.php")
        ));
```

On my script written in vue js, I'm using axios, grabbing the ajaxurl and sending the required information.

```
const response = await this.$http.post(wp_vue.ajaxurl, {
        data: { action: "blackout_admin_test" }
      });
```

My server gives the following output:

```
172.18.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2020:17:36:50 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 400 11 "http://localhost/wp-admin/admin.php?page=guides" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2020:17:36:58 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 58 "http://localhost/wp-admin/admin.php?page=guides" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0" "-"
```

My javascript console gives me the following error:

```
Error: "Request failed with status code 400"
    createError createError.js:16
    settle settle.js:17
    handleLoad xhr.js:59
```

My wordpress server output:

```
webserver    | 172.18.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2020:17:56:36 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 400 11 "http://localhost/wp-admin/admin.php?page=guides" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0" "-"
wordpress    | 172.18.0.3 -  05/Jan/2020:17:56:36 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 400
```

So I guess my question is what am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [admin-ajax.php doesn't work when using POST data and Axios](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307193/admin-ajax-php-doesnt-work-when-using-post-data-and-axios)